# How to return a number/variable with an observable in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, observable

I've got an angular service calling an API and returning a large amount of data. In that same GET call, I'm doing some logic that counts how many of each type there are.  My question is simple, can I send back that variable/number with the data, or even save it to another variable and send that?

When I attempt to save it to the service as a public variable, it's undefined when I try to pull it into another component.   I'm assuming because the variable gets accessed before the observable is subscribed to, but I don't know how to remedy this?

In the code below, _counts is what I'm trying to return, which works fine logging inside the getPciInfo method, but like I said, it comes back as undefined anywhere else. (i'm trying to pass this number to a different component).

Thanks for any help or advice you can offer.

```
public _counts: any;

getPciInfo(): Observable <Ipcidata[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Ipcidata[]>('http://dr0-hlp-07/api/PCIMachines')
      .pipe(
              map(results => {

                const sorted = results.sort(( a, b ) => {
                      const updateDateA = Date.parse(this.datepipe.transform(a.UpdatedDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy'));
                      const carda = determineCardType(a, this.dateMinusMonth, this.dateMinusTwoWeeks)
                      const cardb = determineCardType(b, this.dateMinusMonth, this.dateMinusTwoWeeks)

                      return cardb - carda
                });

                this._counts = sorted.reduce((acc, cur)=>{
                  const cardType = determineCardType(cur, this.dateMinusMonth, this.dateMinusTwoWeeks)

                  switch (cardType) {
                    case 1:
                      acc.green += 1;
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      acc.yellow += 1;
                      break;
                    case 3:
                      acc.red += 1;
                      break;
                  }
                  return acc;
                }, {
                  red: 0,
                  green: 0,
                  yellow: 0
                });
                console.log(this._counts)
                console.log(this._counts.red)

          return sorted;
          }
```

Comment: `return ({sorted, counts: _counts})` and in your subscription you can get `result.sorted` and `result.counts`. Or you can have a `Subject` for `counts` if you want to subscribe to it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send back the count you can do:

```
return ({sorted, counts: _counts});
```

To share it across components from this service you can have a subject, something like:

```
private countsSource = new Subject();
private counts = this.countsSource.asObservable();

getPciInfo(): Observable <Ipcidata[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Ipcidata[]>('http://dr0-hlp-07/api/PCIMachines')
      .pipe(
              map(results => {
                 ....
                 const counts = ...
                 this.countsSource.next(counts)
              });
}

getCounts(): Observable<CountData> {
     return this.counts;
}
```

In a component you can consume it just like the other function

```
this.myService.getCounts().subscribe(counts => console.log(counts));
```

If you want the counts to be sent to new Subscriptions, you may have to use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: this is what I'm looking for, but I'm getting  the following error, I'm assuming because I'm not specifying an extra variable as a return?

```Type 'Observable<{ sorted: Ipcidata[]; counts: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Ipcidata[]>```

Not sure exactly where to do that, as I can't do it in the getPciInfo() method without an error.

Comment: You just have to change the return type of the method to `Observable<{ sorted: Ipcidata[], counts: any }>` as you are no longer returning `Observable<Ipcidata[]>`. Or create an iterface for Ipcidata + count and use it as return type.

Comment: This worked, I just wasn't adding it as a return type correctly inside of brackets, thank you.!